# Convert nvarchar to DateTime returns back different dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

Why the result of this two nvarchar to DateTime is different?

```
Declare @ApplyDate nvarchar(max)
Set @ApplyDate =  N'2014-01-01' 

Print  CONVERT(datetime,  @ApplyDate , 120) 
Exec('  print  CONVERT(datetime,  ' + @ApplyDate + ', 120)  ')
```

result is:

```
Jan  1 2014 12:00AM
Jul  6 1905 12:00AM
```

Comment: For a start, why are you storing a date as a varchar?

Comment: @RichBenner Im not just want to know why we have this different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this query:

```
Exec('  print  CONVERT(datetime,  ' + @ApplyDate + ', 120)  ')
```

you are inserting `@ApplyDate` without quotes, which effectively turns into:

```
print  CONVERT(datetime,  2014-01-01, 120)
```

which is of course equivalent to:

```
print  CONVERT(datetime,  2012, 120)
```

where 2012 is read as number of days passed starting on 1900-01-01.

You are probably looking for (note additional pair of quotes):

```
Exec('  print  CONVERT(datetime,  ''' + @ApplyDate + ''', 120)  ')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed extra single quotes around string value in your second example, so it doesn't get recognized as string.

It should be

```
Exec('  print  CONVERT(datetime,  ''' + @ApplyDate + ''', 120)  ')
```

In this case both examples outputs same date.

Answer (score 1):

In your `EXEC` statement, you are missing the quotes around `@ApplyDate` and it's being parsed as a numeric calculation:

```
2014 - 01 - 01 = 2012
```

Which when converted into a date is correctly `Jul  6 1905 12:00AM`.

Try:

```
Exec('  print  CONVERT(datetime,  ''' + @ApplyDate + ''', 120)  ')
```

Answer (score 0):

in the 2nd you are converting the result of 2014 minus 1 minus 1 to date

see

```
Declare @ApplyDate nvarchar(max),
    @str    nvarchar(max)

Set @ApplyDate =  N'2014-01-01' 

Print  CONVERT(datetime,  @ApplyDate , 120) 
Exec('  print  CONVERT(datetime,  ' + @ApplyDate + ', 120)  ')

select  @str = '  print  CONVERT(datetime,  ' + @ApplyDate + ', 120)  '

print   @str
```